# How to get array allocation with JProfiler

Tags: jprofiler

My spark java application is running on remote machine in our internal lab. To analyse the memory consumption of remote application, attached the remote application pid to JProfiler by using the 'attach mode' (with help of jpenable) from my local machine.

After attaching the remote application to JProfiler in local machine, 'Allocation tree' is showing only **non-array** object allocations. I want to know array allocations also from my local machine.

Please help me to know about the array allocation with JProfiler.

Thanks,
Nagendra R

Answer (score 1):

When you attach to a running JVM with the JProfiler GUI, the session startup dialog has an option "Record array allocations". It is not selected by default, because it requires a large amount of reinstrumentations which can be very slow.

If array allocation spots are important for your analysis, it's better not to use attach mode but to pass the VM parameter for profiling as given by

Session->Integration wizards->New remote integration

Then the instrumentation is done while the classes are loaded.